# Node taxonomy now appears vertically in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

After migration to Drupal 7 the taxonomy terms now appear vertically with the vocabulary names, and it seems to be the result of Drupal 7 converting taxonomies into fields.

Is there a way to revert to Drupal 6 behaviour, ie just display the taxonomy terms horizontally as before?

Comment: its just a little CSS ...

Comment: could you be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After bringing in Firebug these are the changes I made

```
# display blocks for present taxonomy inline
.field-type-taxonomy-term-reference {
    display:inline-block;
}

# display taxonomy terms inline 
.field-type-taxonomy-term-reference .field-item {
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 11px;
}

# hide labels for Taxonomies, display terms only
.field-type-taxonomy-term-reference .field-label {
    display: none;
}
```

There is a page on Drupal.org that pretty much does the same thing, but the CSS is applied at node level - http://drupal.org/node/1684762

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you want display terms in node view horizontally, then:

if your node-type is `xxxx` and you vocabulary name is `yyyy`, add this to your CSS files:

```
.node-xxxx .field-name-field-yyyy .field-item {
  display: inline;
}
```

Comment: It will be awkward to apply your answer for every node or field indivually. Something works for all nodes is required